# How to remove duplicates entries from a file using shell

Tags: shell

I have a file that is in the format:

```
0000000540|Q1.1|margi|Q1.1|margi|Q1.1|margi
0099940598|Q1.2|8888|Q1.3|5454|Q1.2|8888    
0000234223|Q2.10|saigon|Q3.9|tango|Q1.1|money
```

I am trying to remove the duplicates that appear on the same line.

So, if a line has

```
0000000540|Q1.1|margi|Q1.1|margi|Q1.1|margi
```

I'll like it to be

```
0000000540|Q1.1|margi
```

If the line has

```
0099940598|Q1.2|8888|Q1.3|5454|Q1.2|8888
```

I'll like it to be like

```
0099940598|Q1.2|8888|Q1.3|5454
```

I would like to do this on a shell script that takes an input file and outputs the file without the duplicates.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help

Comment: which shell and which version?

Comment: There seem to be pairs Qx|val. Are the pairs always matching? Do you want to preserve order, or would `0099940598|8888|5454|Q1.3|Q1.2|` be acceptable? I don't guess so. Can `0|Q1|4|Q1|5` happen?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it but may not be efficient for large files.

```
awk '
    {
        delete p;
        n = split($0, a, "|");

        printf("%s", a[1]);

        for (i = 2; i <= n ; i++)
        {
                if (!(a[i] in p))
                {
                    printf("|%s", a[i]);
                    p[a[i]] = "";
                }
        }

        printf "\n";
    }
' YourFileName
```

Comment: Thanks. The file is not that big, around 100k lines. The script helped tremendously.